# How do I debug this reported error in Chrome's console?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, console

Chrome's console reports an error.

It lists the name of a function -- presumably, the one where an error is happening.

It doesn't break.  It doesn't tell me any further details.  I can't make it break with the "Pause on Exceptions" button.

Is there some step that I'm missing for what to do with this error?  What does Chrome intend for me to do?  This is a frequently-called function, so narrowing it down on the particular use case is a fickle problem.

"It doesn't actually help any more than that" is a perfectly acceptable answer.  I just wanted that confirmed or refuted as I continue to battle with this cryptic console output.

[image: This is the expanded "<error>" message. ResolveRests is my function.]

Comment: well, you could start by telling us what frameworks you use, what is in that `main.js` and what are the codes near line 858.

Comment: I usually `console.log(...)` many statements (numbers, variables, anything) around my code to pin-point errors. Have you tried that?

Comment: I sometimes use `debugger;` to try to find the spot where the error occurs.

Comment: Derek, I'd love to know more about "debugger;".   To the other two kind gents, thank you for offering to debug my logic, but I'm a bit too proud for that -- I mainly want to know what Chrome offers in the way of debugging tools, much in the way that I would like to know you can expand the error by clicking the horizontal triangle! An understanding of the tools so I can solve the problem more efficiently, meself, see?  Thanks!

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer, I use javascript from scratch, I believe.  I draw straight to the canvas using lines and dots and pixels.  I may be mistaken, here, as I've only started learning javascript recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in most cases the answer would be to break on exceptions, as I showed in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10860156/200291), that appears to not be the case here.

The problem is likely caused by some code which causes generating a stack trace to fail. Here's a portion of [the relevant code in V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/messages.js?r=11674#1048):

```js
function FormatStackTrace(error, frames) {
  var lines = [];
  try {
    lines.push(error.toString());
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      lines.push("<error: " + e + ">");
    } catch (ee) {
      lines.push("<error>");
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
    var frame = frames[i];
    var line;
    try {
      line = frame.toString();
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        line = "<error: " + e + ">";
      } catch (ee) {
        // Any code that reaches this point is seriously nasty!
        line = "<error>";
      }
    }
    lines.push("    at " + line);
  }
  return lines.join("\n");
}
```

As you can see, you will get `<error>` if it fails to get a string representation of an uncaught exception or a stack frame, and then when it tries to get the string representation of *that*, it fails. For example, if you run this code:

```js
function NastyException() {}
NastyException.prototype.toString = function() { throw this; };
throw new NastyException();
```

Then you'll get this unhelpful error:

```
Uncaught #<error>
```

Admittedly that's not quite the error that you were receiving, but it's not that far off.

Answer (score 2):

Try breaking on exceptions. You can do this by clicking on the [image: stop sign with pause icon] button.

It toggles between three colors: black, blue, and purple.

When it is black, it is not breaking on exceptions.
When it is blue, it is breaking on all exceptions.
When it is purple, it is breaking on uncaught exceptions.

Comment: I should note that this button is in the toolbar of the Script tab.

Comment: I believe I tried it on purple and black.  I shall try blue!  If it breaks on the error, you've earned yourself some glory, sir!

Comment: It did not break on blue.  Blast!

Comment: @Danny: I hope you're not running into [this](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/messages.js?r=11674#1048). (I searched for `<error>` in the V8 source)

Comment: First off, I love users like you. When we have newcomers that don't know how answers come about, it's users like you that explain it (in the V8 source). That truly helps overall. Thanks. Secondly, I think you're on to something. Perhaps the code is simply too nasty to report!  Could you list your comment as an answer?

Comment: For those encountering the same problem:

The answer is icktoofay's comment, which led to seeing it's just really nasty code that isn't deciphered by the V8 engine.  Since the comment is under this answer, I just marked it as the answer because icktoofay probably doesn't care for any more points.

Comment: @Danny: I'm sorry; I must have missed the "add it as an answer" part. I'll add it; just a moment.